# ASP.Net Httpcontext.Current.User shows last user who spawned thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-config, windows-authentication

Very strange issue I'm facing with ASP.Net and Current User.

Using ASP.Net 4.0.

For some reason, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name reports the User Identity as the last person who hit the server. In other words, it somehow and for some reason caches the Identity.

Heres the scenario: 
Log in on computer 1 with my own username and it shows fine.
Log in on computer 2 with other username and it shows fine.

Refresh Browser on Computer 1 and it shows computer 2 credentials!!!

I've tried just about everything! I had a custom role provider which I turned off and tried every possible setting. Currently I have two lines in my web config which should work just fine.

I've checked the following in IIS: 
Anonymous is disabled
Windows is enabled
Disabled Session State!

To test the username, I'm doing this :

```
lblUserName.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?
Could this be because i'm using NTLM and not Kerberos?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the issue in a new project?

Comment: I'll try that quickly and come back

Comment: Mmmm, issue not happening in new project... must be web.config issue somewhere....

Comment: Do you happen to have custom membership (not role) provider enabled? Can you provide your Forms Authentication settings?

Comment: I've disabled Custom RoleManager but the rest was all stock standard. I've even gone as far as to disable Membership, Profile and RoleManager completely and only using     <authentication mode="Windows" />

Answer (score 1):

Holy Smokes, what a stupid issue! I found the answer by ripping apart the web.config.

Turns out caching was the issue. I had the following as enabled in my web.config :

> ```
> <caching enabled="false">
>   <profiles>
>     <add duration="72:00:00" location="Client" extension=".aspx" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
>     <add duration="72:00:00" location="Client" extension=".axd" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
>     <add duration="72:00:00" location="Client" extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
>     <add duration="72:00:00" location="Client" extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
>     <add duration="72:00:00" location="Client" extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
>     <add duration="72:00:00" location="Client" extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
>     <add duration="72:00:00" location="Client" extension=".gif" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
>   </profiles>
> </caching>
> ```

Disabling caching fixed it!
What a strange issue.

Comment: You have enabled caching of dynamic content like aspx files.

Comment: Which isn't a good thing now is it!!! This also explains a whole lot of other issues i've been having!! Bonehead move, but at least its sorted!