# User.Identity.Name in _Layout of MVC3 project returns wrong user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Within the view, we simply have: @User.Identity.Name

Everything works fine in every environment except our production environment.
If 2 or more users constantly refresh their browser, eventually, the name returned is NOT their own. Seems like it may be a caching issue, but what is being cached and why? This behavior is consistent in IE and Chrome, so it isn't some funky IE caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution here:

[ASP.Net Httpcontext.Current.User shows last user who spawned thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939249/asp-net-httpcontext-current-user-shows-last-user-who-spawned-thread)

Turns out I just needed to add the following to the web.config:

```
<caching enabled="false" />
```